# Historical ISM report on business?

Tags: data, backtesting

Is there any place to download historical ISM ROB (report on business)? The website only shows current and previous month. [ISM ROB](https://www.ismworld.org/supply-management-news-and-reports/reports/ism-report-on-business/pmi/april/)

Comment: By report on business, do you want the numerical time series history, or the history of the text in the report  itself? The former can be found pretty easily, the latter is probably very tough to find.

Comment: Yes, I need the report itself.

Comment: The folks at Bloomberg seemed to transcribe some of them: https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2013-10-01/u-s-september-ism-manufacturing-report-on-business-text-

Comment: You'd need to be a subscriber, and set up the appropriate scraping machinery. As well as find all the correct URLs, which you might be able to systematically guess.

Comment: I've actually managed to get everything from 2009-2015 using the archive.org wayback machine. The data is sparse before and after that date range. I'll look into this Bloomberg thing, although I'm wanting a complete dataset going back as far as possible.